# Как упростить вложенные слушатели анимаций

Tags: android, шаблоны-проектирования, android-animation

Есть приложение с экраном регистрации. По итогу нажатия кнопки, должна запускаться анимация появления белого экрана, затем должна запускаться анимация другого элемента, а потом должна запускаться анимация исчезновения этого элемента и все это друг за другом. Иначе, принцип можно описать так:

Нажата кнопка **->** старт анимации появления белого экрана (по сути `RelativeView` с `background` = `white`) **->** под конец этой анимации, у `view` (Которая лежит в `RelativeLayout`) ставится `alpha` = 1 и запускается следующая анимация **->** под конец анимации `view`, она должна медленно исчезнуть. Соответственно, это новая анимация исчезновения.

Таким образом получается 3 вложенных слушателя анимаций (в примере кода пока 2).

```
@Override
    public void showDoneView(){
        Animator animator = Flubber.with()
                .animation(Flubber.AnimationPreset.FADE_IN)
                .duration(1000)
                .createFor(doneLayout);
        animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation){

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation){
                doneView.setAlpha(1f);
                doneView.setSpeed(0.7f);
                doneView.playAnimation();
                doneView.addAnimatorListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation){

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation){
                        MyApp.INSTANCE.getRouter().newRootScreen(FEED_FRAGMENT_TAG);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation){

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation){

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation){

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation){

            }
        });
        animator.start();

    }
```

Мне необходим какой-нибудь паттерн, который упростит работу с вложенными слушателями.

Единственное упрощение, которое я здесь вижу пока что- вынесение создания слушателей анимаций в отдельный метод для каждого экземпляра.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте класс который реализует Animator.AnimatorListener с пустыми методами, потом когда вам нужен будет какой-то определенный из них то его переопределите и все.

**Пример:**

```
public class SimpleAnimatorListener implements Animator.AnimatorListener {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation){

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation){

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation){

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation){

                }
  }
```

**Далее используем так:**

```
animator.addListener(new SimpleAnimatorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation){        
       MyApp.INSTANCE.getRouter().newRootScreen(FEED_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    }
});
```